# How to add more whitespace between paragraphs on wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress, whitespace, line-breaks

I have a default spacing between paragraphs on my posts but is there a way to add extra space in some posts? I tried using break tags but wp removes then after I click save.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be using CSS

In the HTML edit mode add something like this.

```
<p class="extra_space"> Some paragraph content here</p>
```

then in styles.css in your theme

```
p.extra_space {
padding-top:15px;
}
```

You can change the padding/margin to as much or as little as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into HTML mode in the editor you can insert an empty line by putting in

```
<br>
```

Use multiple tags for multiple lines.  I don't recall having this issue in Wordpress, it may be based on your theme?

Comment: If I recall if you add `<br>` in WYSIWYG mode WordPress stips the tags. So maybe  you wern't in HTML mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<b>&nbsp;</b>`  which is a nonbreaking space between bold tags, which makes WP think there is content so it will add a paragraph break.

Or use the nonautop plugin to do all your own formatting: [WordPress › NoAutoP « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/noautop/)